# Unused variable warning on for each loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, ios

I've got an array of NSNumber objects created thusly:

```
        myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.0],
                [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.0],
                [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.0],
                [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.0],
                [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.0], nil];
```

(Though just occurred to me that I could have done

```
myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: object1, etc..., nil];
```

and skipped the alloc entirely. Which would be better?)

Anyway, it's tangential to my question:

Over the life of the app, the values get changed. At a certain point, I want to reset them all to zero. Here's how I'm doing it now:

```
 for (NSNumber *number in myArray) {
     number = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.0];
 }
```

But the Static Analyzer throws a warning because it thinks 'number' is an unused variable (which it technically is - set and then never used again). Is there a better way to zero out all the elements of the array? Perhaps replace the array with a new one? What would be fastest and avoid the static analysis warning?

Comment: For people from the future who are coming across this question: as of iOS 6 and Mountain Lion, you can use new Obj-C literals, so `[NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.0]` becomes `@0.0`, and `[NSArray arrayWithObjects: obj1, obj2, ..., nil]` becomes `@[obj1, obj2, ...]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With regards to creating an array, remember that `alloc`+`initWithObjects:` requires an explicit release afterwards, whereas the `arrayWithObjects:` convenience method does not (and also, it will not survive an iteration of the run loop unless you retain it).

```
for (NSNumber *number in myArray) {
    number = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.0];
}
```

This loop doesn't do what you think it does. `number` simply *points* to an `NSNumber` instance, and all you're doing is changing `number` to point to another instance of `NSNumber`, it does not modify the original instance of `NSNumber` in `myArray`.

`NSNumber` instances are immutable, so the only way to set them all to zero would be to completely erase the contents of `myArray` and fill it back up with `[NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.0]`

```
NSUInteger count = [myArray count];
[myArray removeAllObjects];

while(count--)
    [myArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.0]];
```

Comment: You can avoid iterating through the array twice by using `-replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` in your while loop.  Then you don't need to `-removeAllObjects`